# how does maven-spring-boot-plugin determine the main class?

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven

I am quite new to the java world, and recently I have been trying to grasp some ideas about how spring-boot works.

I am confused about some questions.

1, when I do `mvn install`, does the compiler normally compile all the classes in the `src/main/java` dir, even among them some are not used ?

2, I know somehow the plugin `maven-spring-boot-plugin` defined in `pom.xml` does all the magic for a spring application to start up, but, how does it determine which class is the Main-Class ? via traversing all the compiled classes to find one with `public static void main` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes, compile everything in the "ClassPath". In this case is the `src/main/java` you mentioned.
2. It will look for the main method which is in a class with `@SpringBootApplication` annotation.

Comment: so, in this way, if I have way too many redundant class definitions, 1, the compiler will still compile every class ? and, 2, spring-boot-plugin will look into every compiled class to find a proper one ? wouldn't it be a tough job ?

Comment: Yes, `mvn install`, everything in the classpath will be compiled no matter they are used or not. Underneath the spring-boot, it does not really scan through all the classes to find the main method. The annotation is a shortcut for it to find the main method. You can think of annotation like a property. These properties tell the Spring Boot what those classes or methods are for.